automatizando descarga de pdf de una web con python
Hola tengo el siguiente codigo, me funciona hasta cierta parte. me lleva hasta el visor de pdf de adobe, el cual abre 10 o mas archivos y alli es donde no hace nada mas el programa, como podria solucionarlo para que al abrir el visor de pdf descargue los archivos.
class DescargaPDFBot:
    def __init__(self, url_base):
        self.url_base = url_base

    def descargar_pdf(self, destino):
        # Configuración de Selenium
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True  # Para ejecución sin abrir ventana del navegador
        service = Service('C:/Users/auxiliares/Documents/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe')  # Ruta al chromedriver

        # Inicializar el navegador
        with webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options) as driver:
            # Navegar a la URL base
            driver.get(self.url_base)

            # Esperar un momento para que se carguen las casillas de selección y el botón de descarga
            time.sleep(20)  # Ajusta el tiempo según sea necesario

            # Después de marcar manualmente las casillas de selección, encontrar y hacer clic en el botón de descarga
            boton_descarga = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='RB001-btnIconEl']")
            boton_descarga.click()

            # Esperar un momento para que se abra el visor de PDF
            time.sleep(15)  # Ajusta el tiempo según sea necesario

            # Obtener todos los enlaces de descarga en el visor de PDF(ACA DEBE ESTAR EL ERROR O FALTA DE CODIGO)
            enlaces_descarga = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')]")
            
            # Iterar sobre los enlaces y descargar cada PDF individualmente
            for enlace in enlaces_descarga:
                # Obtener el URL del enlace de descarga
                url_pdf = enlace.get_attribute('href')
                
                # Simular un clic en el enlace para iniciar la descarga
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", enlace)
                
                # Esperar un momento para que se inicie la descarga
                time.sleep(2)  # Ajusta el tiempo según sea necesario



No utilices time.sleep, vas a perder mucho tiempo, en cambio importa from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC y utiliza la siguiente estructura element = WebDriverWait(driver, tiempo).until(EC.metodo((By.METODO, "identificador"))). También mírate requests

perdon, no se mucho de python, podrias guiarme un poco mas ?

time.sleep para el programa y continua después de cierto tiempo. Con el método que te he dicho esperarás solo hasta cuando el elemento esté presente en la página y no perderás tanto tiempo. Mírate esta página. Para recibir respuestas, por favor, muestra una imagen de la página o el código completo para que podamos hacer pruebas y nos sea más fácil

ya he añadido una imagen de lcodigo no se si te sea clara

Si el problema es que abre los archivos, no los descargues con Chrome. Usa una librería u otra cosa para descargarlos.
